# How to programmatically fire ondblclick event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am trying the following simple code (in html, using js on IE8):

```
<input type="image" src="pic.jpg" id="aa" ondblclick="alert('aa');"/>
<script>
document.getElementById('aa').dblclick(); 
</script>
```

and I get an error that: object doesn't support this property or method (regarding the script part). And I don't get the alert.

Whereas when I dblclick on the image, I get the alert message.
So I wish to know how to programmatically fire the dblclick event (without actually double clicking the image).

The same works just fine with onclick (instead of on dblclick).
I also tried it on button, input text. Same error .

Answer (score 7):

The property name is `ondblclick` but you're attempting to call `dblclick`.  You need to call `ondblclick`.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('aa').ondblclick(); 
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frwpY/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<input type="image" src="pic.jpg" id="aa" ondblclick="alert('aa');"/>
<script>
document.getElementById('aa').ondblclick(); 
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnUZY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check out MDNs article about [`element.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent)

Sample code from MDN:

```
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox"); 
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

This way you can also track the event through the DOM bubble and make sure it wasn't canceled.